# Ayuda con array con PHP

Tags: php, json

```
 while ($row=pg_fetch_array($query_cita)){
       $jsonData = array(
            'OrdenHis' => $row['ordenHis'], //# orden
            'OrdenSendMIS' => $row['MiS'],
            'Historia' => $row['Historia'],
        );
 }           
        $jsonDataEncoded = '['.json_encode($jsonData).']';
```

Obtengo esto:

> [{"OrdenHis":"20000853","OrdenSendMIS":"20000853","Historia":"98435"}]

La siguiente vez que se ejecuta el while anadir un diccionario para al final obtener esto:

> [{"OrdenHis":"20000853","OrdenSendMIS":"210000853","Historia":"98435"},
>   {"OrdenHis":"30000854","OrdenSendMIS":"31000854","Historia":"98436"}]

y asi sucesivamente...

Alguien me puede guiar

Comment: Tu quieres hacer eso ? o lo que tienes hasta ahora arroja algún error ?

Comment: Antes del final del while anadi esto:  array_push($jsonData, $jsonData); y obtengo esto: [{"OrdenHis":"20000853","OrdenSendMIS":"210000853","Historia":"98435", "0": {"OrdenHis":"30000854","OrdenSendMIS":"31000854","Historia":"98436"}}], que esta incorrecto

Comment: Lo unico que necesitas es agregar esto: 
`$jsonData[] = array(
            'OrdenHis' => $row['ordenHis'], //# orden
            'OrdenSendMIS' => $row['MiS'],
            'Historia' => $row['Historia'],
        );`

Comment: Deja ver si entiendo, lo que pasa es que solo estas obteniendo 1 solo valor al final y no el conjunto de valores, osea un array estructurado a tu manera

Comment: @ManueelPerezz perfecto, tu solución funciona perfecto.

Comment: @RobertoFeijoo un placer!